# Rewrite - Redirecting all without index.php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a index.php file blank and Loader.php file in my root folder and have the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule . Loader.php [L]
```

When i remove the index.php file (it has nothing) Rewrite does not work and the Apache back an "Index of".

How to delete the "index.php" and keep Rewrite working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing your rule's pattern from `.` to `^`. The `.` means there must be *at least one* character in the request. If you try loading `/` (which is a blank request), the `.` pattern won't match it. Then, because you have an index file, that gets mapped and the index file gets put through the rules. The second time around `.` matches because there's characters in the request.

```
RewriteRule ^ Loader.php [L]
```

Comment: The request is also faster? I realized that my site was faster.